# How to import custom Python module into Snowflake and use it in Snowpark UDF?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a custom Python module `test_model` that contains the function `return_string`:

```
#test_module.py
def return_string(value):
    return value + ' from function'
```

I created a stage `PUBLIC.TEST_STAGE` and uploaded the file `test_model.py` to the `TEST_STAGE`.
Then I tried the below approach:

```
session.add_import('@PUBLIC.TEST_STAGE/test_module.py')
session.add_packages("test_module")
```

But I got the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot add package test_module because it is not available in Snowflake.
```

I tried also this:

```
session.add_import('@PUBLIC.TEST_STAGE/test_module.py')
import test_module
```

But I got another error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_module'
```

It is interesting that `session.add_import` doesn't fail if the path to the file is misspelled, e.g. like this:

```
session.add_import('@PUBLICE.TEST_STAGE_1/test_module_0.py') # No error
```

How could I import this module into Snowflake and use the function `return_string` there?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```py
session.add_import('@PUBLIC.TEST_STAGE/test_module.py')
import sys
import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
sys.path.append(import_dir + "test_module.py")
import test_module
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wondering if you are missing two concepts.

Locally you can just do something like `import test_module` and as long as the file can be found in your `PYTHONPATH` it will loaded with no problems.

If you create function that you want to run inside of an UDF then you need to make the module available. To do that you will do:

```py
from snowflake.snowpark import Session, Column
from snowflake.snowpark import functions as F, types as T
import json, os; configs = json.load(open(os.path.expanduser('~/credentials.json')))
session = Session.builder.configs(configs).create()
session.use_database("snowpark_testdb")
session.add_import('test_module.py')
def foo():
    import test_module # <= to use this inside of snowflake you need to make this available
    return test_module.return_string('hello')
my_foo_udf = session.udf.register(foo, return_type=T.StringType(), input_types=None)
# For a temporal UDF you dont need to specify the stage for a permanent udf just specify the stage
session.create_dataframe(["world"],schema=["col1"]).with_column("foo",my_foo_udf()).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Medium Article-
https://medium.com/snowflake/introducing-simple-workflow-for-using-python-packages-in-snowpark-928f667ff1aa

Option 1: Add your package while registering your UDF or stored procedure.

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
session = snowpark.Session.builder.configs(CONNECTION_PARAMETERS).create()

session.custom_packages_usage_config = {
  "enabled": True
}

@udf(name="my_udf", packages=["scikit-fuzzy==0.4.2"])
def my_udf_function():
  import skfuzzy as fuzz
  # ...

@sproc(name="my_sproc", packages=["scikit-fuzzy==0.4.2"])
def my_stored_procedure(session):
  import skfuzzy as fuzz
  # ...
```

Option 2: Add your package to a requirements.txt file.

```
# my_requirements_file.txt
scikit-fuzzy==0.4.2
# add your other requirements here.
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
session = snowpark.Session.builder.configs(CONNECTION_PARAMETERS).create()
session.custom_packages_usage_config = {"enabled": True}
session.add_requirements("./my_requirements_file.txt")

# Any UDF/stored procedure created using session object can now use the scikit-fuzzy module, as long as the `packages` and `imports` arguments are not mentioned while registering your UDFs/stored procedures.
```

Option 3: Add your package to a Conda environment.yaml file (Docs).

```
# my_environment_file.yml
name: my_environment  # Name of the environment

dependencies:  # List of packages and versions to include in the environment
  - python=3.9.1 # Python version
  - pip=23.1.2
  - pip:
    - scikit-fuzzy==0.4.2
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
session = snowpark.Session.builder.configs(CONNECTION_PARAMETERS).create()
session.custom_packages_usage_config = {"enabled": True}
session.add_requirements("./my_environment_file.yml")
```

Option 4: Add your packages viaSession.add_packages (Docs).

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
session = snowpark.Session.builder.configs(CONNECTION_PARAMETERS).create()
session.custom_packages_usage_config = {"enabled": True}
session.add_packages(["scikit-fuzzy==0.4.2"])
```